# Is it possible to change position of total/sum rows in SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I need to design a SlikGrid table that displays it's group totals in the same row as a group header title. Default behaviour, that I have not been able to modify yet, displays group aggregates always at the end of the group.

The same goes for to absolute totals. The sum row is always displayed at the bottom of the table. Is it possible (even with some fiddling with internals) to move the sum row to the top and sit there as excel-like fixed header?

**Update:**
I discovered that by setting flag *lazyTotalsCalculation* of object passed to setGrouping to false the totals are available at the time of the group row formatting.
So Case #1 can be solved with the help of this, however. I'd still prefer cleaner solution.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132043/slickgrid-display-aggregation-at-grouping-level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been researching how to do this very thing and have spent several hours trying to figure it out, and I have come up with ad hoc solution. I display all my aggregate columns as the last group of columns in my grid. In order to arrange them differently (as in intermittent aggregate columns), you will have to tweak my custom metadata function.

The issue lies in `groupitemmetadataprovider.js`:

```
function getGroupRowMetadata(item) {
      return {
        selectable: false,
        focusable: options.groupFocusable,
        cssClasses: options.groupCssClass,
        columns: {
          0: {
            colspan: "*",
            formatter: options.groupFormatter,
            editor: null
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

It returns only one column per group, hence the group row that spans the entire grid.

In order to change this, I first edited `groupitemmetadataprovider.js` by appending the following within `var _defaults`: `getGroupRowMetadata: getGroupRowMetadata,`.

Then, in the `return` value near the bottom of the file, I changed `"getGroupRowMetadata":getGroupRowMetadata` to the following: `"getGroupRowMetadata":options.getGroupRowMetadata`.

I then copied and tweaked the `defaultGroupCellFormatter` and `defaultTotalsCellFormatter`function from `groupitemmetadataprovider.js` into the `<script>` tag in my html file:

```
function tweakedGroupCellFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, item) {
    //removed initial conditional statement
    var indentation = item.level * 15 + "px";
    return "<span class='slick-group-toggle " +
        (item.collapsed ? "collapsed'" : "expanded'") +
        "' style='margin-left:" + indentation +"'>" +
        "</span>" +
        "<span class='slick-group-title' level='" + item.level + "'>" +
        item.title +
        "</span>";
}

function tweakedTotalsCellFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, item) {
    //pass in item.totals instead of just item to your formatters
    var cell_value = (columnDef.groupTotalsFormatter && columnDef.groupTotalsFormatter(item.totals, columnDef)) || "";
    //if you want to apply the same css styling as the group title
    //if not, just return cell_value as is
    return "<span class='slick-group-title' level='" + item.level + "'>" +
        cell_value +
        "</span>";
}
```

My custom metadata function to overwrite the initial one:

```
function groupTotalsRowMetadata(item) {
    var get_cols = {
        //keep the original grouping title but change the colspan
        0: {
            colspan: get_colspan - aggregate_list.length,
            formatter: tweakedGroupCellFormatter,
            editor: null
        }
    }
    //loop through and define the remaining group row columns and provide the totals formatter
    //customize this step to assign the formatter to the the columns that you want totaled
    for (var i = get_colspan - aggregate_list.length + 1, ii = get_colspan; i < ii; i++) {
        get_cols[i] = {
            colspan: 1,
            formatter: tweakedTotalsCellFormatter,
            editor: null
        };
    }
    return {
        selectable: false,
        focusable: true,
        //optionally add group-row-level class for custom styling like so
        //this will be applied to every group row at item.level
        cssClasses: "slick-group level-" + item.level,
        columns: get_cols
    };
}
```

And finally, initialize the provider with the custom metadata function:

```
var groupItemMetaDataProvider = new Slick.Data.GroupItemMetadataProvider({groupRowMetadata:groupTotalsRowMetadata});
dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({groupItemMetadataProvider: groupItemMetadataProvider, inlineFilters: true});
grid = new Slick.Grid("#mygrid", dataView, columns, options);
grid.registerPlugin(groupItemMetadataProvider);
```

And many moons later, you will have a group row that will only span a defined number of columns and add totals to the other columns in the row with the traditional grid formatting.

Comment: could you please share the code. I'm unable get the functionality ..@ionalchemist

Comment: the answer is very clear. thanks for that.
I tried it with the latest version of slickgrid.
The totals came along with the heading correctly.
however if I collapse and expand some group, the functionality is lost.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I forgot to set  "lazyTotalsCalculation: false". It worked now. thanks.

Comment: get_colspan and aggregate_list are null? where are they defined?

Comment: Been awhile since I last looked and I don't have access to the code atm, but I seem to remember those variables being global in one of the files included with slickgrid...I can take a closer look sometime next week, but you should be able to find them yourself with a little digging around

Answer (score 0):

You can add the sum container in the header column when specifing columns and then update it every time the grid is databound

```
var myData;
var column = { id: "MyColumn", name: "MyColumn <span class='summary MyColumn'></span>"};

function OnMyGridReloadData (){
    var summary = {}
    for(i = 0; i < myData.length;i++){
        summary['MyColumn'] += myData[i]['MyColumn'];
    }
    $('.MyColumn.summary').text(summary['MyColumn']);


}
```